# Portable c++ atomic swap (Windows - GNU/Linux - MacOSX)

Tags: c++, portability, swap, atomic

Is there free a **portable** (Windows, GNU/Linux & MacOSX) library providing a **lock-free atomic swap function**?

If not, how would it be implemented for each of these platforms? (x86 with VC++ or g++)

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There's a [lock-free](http://www.boost.org/community/review_schedule.html) library pending review in [boost](http://www.boost.org). Also if you dig into source of [boost smart pointers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/smart_ptr/smart_ptr.htm) library you will find atomic ops inlined for multiple platforms. Another one  - Intel [Threading Building Blocks](http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/) has implementation of `atomic<>` template.

Comment: Right ... which working compiler implementation are talking about?

Answer (score 1):

Depends what you want to swap. In assembler for x86 you might be able to get a "nearly" atomic xor swap, otherwise I'd go with some solution that uses locking, which will differ on Win32/{Linux,Darwin}.

If you are looking for a library, have a look at APR (Apache Portable Runtime) - http://apr.apache.org/

Comment: http://apr.apache.org/docs/apr/1.3/group__apr__atomic.html#ge45c529f14f8489102382bd3fd4cce22 in particular you should use the apr atomic compare and swap, using the same value as comparison. Put it in a while as it's not guaranteed that the swap will take place.

Answer (score 1):

Boost has [a set of macros](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/boost/detail/interlocked.hpp) for facilitating lock-free operations in a portable way.